# Part of a proof that a left $R$-module $M$ is cyclic and every nonzero element generates $M$ if and only if $M\cong R/I$ for a maximal left ideal $I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

I'm trying to follow this proof from Noncommutative Algebra by Farb. The theorem is that the following are equivalent for a left $R$-module $M$:

$(1)$ $M$ is simple

$(2)$ $M$ is cyclic and generated by every nonzero element

$(3)$ $M\cong R/I$ for a maximal left ideal $I$

where we say $M$ is cyclic if $Rm=M$ for some $m\in M$.

The part I'm trying to follow is from $(2)$ implies $(3)$: for any nonzero $m$ define a map $R\to Rm$ by $r\mapsto rm$; this has kernel $I=\text{Ann}(m)$, so $M=Rm\cong R/I$. Then he says that to see $I$ is maximal, note if $I$ weren't maximal then there would be a nonzero element which does not generate $M$. I fail to see why this is true. Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you trying to understand (1) implies (3) or (3) implies (1)? It seems like you're asking how (3) implies (1), but the proof you write is showing (1) implies (3).

Comment: Oh I mistyped, I meant to say (2) implies (3)... I'm not sure how (3) implies (1) came out of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First $(3)$ implies $(1)$. Suppose $M \cong R/I$, with $I$ a maximal ideal in $R$. Then as a ring $R/I$ is a field. Hence the only ideals of $R/I$ are the ring itself and $\{0\}$. But this means that the only subgroups of $R/I$ that are closed under multiplication by elements of $R$ are $R/I$ and $\{0\}$, and so $M$ is a simple module.

For the other direction ($(1)$ implies $(3)$), suppose $M$ is a simple module. Then we know that $M=Rm$, for every nonzero $m \in M$. Hence there is an isomorphism $R/I \cong M$, for some ideal $I \subseteq R$. Suppose $I$ is not maximal. Then there exists $r \in R/I$ such that $(r) \neq (1)$. Otherwise for all $r \in R/I$, the ideal $(r)$ is equal to $R/I$, implying that $R/I$ is a field. Hence there exists a nonzero proper submodule of $M$, contradicting the fact that $M$ is simple. To see this, suppose $r$ maps to $m \in M$. Then $Rm \neq M$, otherwise $(r)=R/I$. But this means $M$ has a nontrivial submodule, contradicting the fact that it is simple. Hence $I$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: @BenWest Thanks I hadn't noticed that. Unfortunately I don't know any noncommutative algebra, but wouldn't the argument still work if we replaced "field" with "division ring" and "ideal" with "left ideal"?

Comment: Essentially, you want to replace field by "simple module." By the correspondence theorem for modules, the submodules of $R/I$ will correspond to submodules of $R$ containing $I$. So if $I$ is maximal, there are only two submodules containing it in $R$, namely $I$ and $R$, so $R/I$ has only two submodules, hence is simple.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Yeah those arguments made sense but it seems you didn't really read my post to see what point I was misunderstanding. I could look up a proof of this fact anywhere, I just wanted help understanding a particular point of the authors proof

Comment: @AlexMathers I agree I apologize for the misunderstanding. As to your question, by Ben West's point, if $I$ were not maximal $R/I$ would contain a nontrivial submodule $J$ (there would be a proper submodule in $R$ containing $I$). It must be then that for all $m \in J$, $(m) \neq (1)$.

Comment: @leibnewtz that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If $I$ were not maximal then there would be an ideal $J$ such that $I \subsetneq J \subsetneq R $.

Let $r \in J $ so that $r \mod I$ does not generate $R/I$. Indeed, since $J$ is an ideal, $R(r \mod I) \subset J/I \subsetneq R/I$

The image of $r$ under the isomorphism $R/I \rightarrow M$ does not generate M.